# How to make a button that dismisses a view presented using UIHostingController/SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui, uihostingcontroller

I have a fairly extensive project that I started with UIKit and now I've decided to use SwiftUI to make some simple form pages, but I need to make a button in SwiftUI to dismiss the current view which is presented with the following code:

```
   func goToSchedule() {
        let vc = UIHostingController(rootView: ScheduleView())
        if let topController = UIApplication.topViewController() {
            topController.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correctly understood code snapshot then `.topViewController()` will be presented `UIHostingViewConroller` when `ScheduleView` shown, so it should inside it like

```
var body: some View {
    // ...
    // somewhere ...

    Button("Close") {
        if let topController = UIApplication.topViewController() {
            topController.dismiss(animated: true)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can dismiss it by holding a reference to it. So hold `vc` in more public scope and dismiss it when you need to.

```
var vc: UIViewController
```

or something like this:

```
if let topController = UIApplication.topViewController() {
    topController.presentedViewController?.dismiss(animated: true)
}
```

Comment: I want to dismiss it using a button inside my SwiftUI view.

Comment: No difference, put the code in a function and call it where you need

Comment: Thanks, it works. For some reason I thought this method wouldn't work with SwiftUI, the only thing here is in my specific case it has to be topController.dismiss(), presentedViewController returns nil.